# How do I run a Postgres query inside my docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using a Windows machine with Postgres 9.5 installed. I've also got a Docker container. I need to run an sql file located specifically inside my docker container, and it's supposed to run the query on Window's Postgres.

How can I do this either using my docker file or my init.sh file (which is called from the docker file).

Comment: If you could add your dockerfile then I think can help you to add your sql file in docker container

Comment: My dockerfile doesn't do anything related to postgres or queries. It does run the init.sh file. 

Inside init.sh there is a python script that is supposed to run a query in postgres but somehow fails.

python /opt/bag/src/createtables.py -q scripts/createtables.sql

For some reason this python script fails with larger queries. When I run the queries inside windows' PGadmin app it does work. So that's why I want to run the psql command directly inside my dockercontainer

Comment: in your docker container, is there any script folder which contians createtables.sql ?

Comment: Yes. it runs multiple scripts in a row, like this:
     python /opt/bag/src/createtables.py -q scripts/createtable1.sql
 python /opt/bag/src/createtables.py -q scripts/createtable2.sql
 python /opt/bag/src/createtables.py -q scripts/dosomething.sql

Most of the time the connection gets closed unexpectedly after running for a while (every query in a row should take about 30 minutes). It appears this python file doesn't have much stamina. The script files exist and are placed properly

Comment: Can you do `exec --it` to a docker container and check is there any dir as `scripts`. If not then you need to copy your `scripts` dir to your container

Comment: The issue is not on the python script, But the problem is connection timeout as you described in the comment. Can you please post the error you are facing, while running script

Comment: I'm 100% sure the scripts exist. This whole container is designed to process a large zip file into a Postgres DB. The whole container works perfectly fine with smaller versions of the zip file.

Comment: The error I get is: 
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly 
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
It is indeed the timeout which causes the error. Like I said, it runs fine when I run the scripts directly in PGAdmin. So I want to somehow call those queries directly from the container.

Answer (score 0):

According to the discussion, the main problem is the connection timeout, and we can increase the connection timeout.

See the official documentation 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/runtime-config-client.html

Here is an example of it working

```
SET statement_timeout = 10000;
SET
test=# SELECT pg_sleep(15);
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

for more info, you can have a look to this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/is-it-possible-to-limit-timeout-on-postgres-server

Comment: So how do I set that variables inside my Dockerfile or .sh file?
I've tried this in the dockerfile: SET statement_timeout = 10;
But it gives me an error saying SET is not found

Comment: ENV <envName > value

Comment: Edit dockerfile  just paste this before spin up the container, ENV env_var_name=value

Comment: So you mean ENV statement_timeout 100000? Or is the ENV name the name of my docker container?

Comment: yes this is enough `ENV statement_timeout 100000` but the question is why you need to set env variable? Just run the command in container!

Comment: Or create a SQL file which will run at the very first place in a python script which will run `SET statement_timeout = 10000;` This is a SQL Command run in postgress to increase connection timeout

Comment: Tried both methods using timeout=0 (so no timeouts), script still gets cut off